# Performance Issue when retrieving transaction details from Quorum Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, quorum

I have experienced performance issue when retrieving transaction details such as transaction originator and transaction recipient 
from the Quorum blockchain.

The Javascript For loop and Web3.eth.contract(abi).at(address2).totalTransactions is used to retrieve transaction details and 
then append to HTML table.

My performance problem is that the retrieval of few lines of transaction data from Quorum blockchain takes about 30 seconds.

Moreover, I am using web3-quorum@0.1.1 and quorum-js@0.3.0.

```
   $('#get-tran').click(() => {
  // Get Tran History
  var tranId = 0;
  let w2Contract=web3w2.eth.contract(abi).at(address2);
  let tottr = w2Contract.totalTransactions();
  //Clear the old table content first
   $("#t02 tr").remove();

  var i=0;
  for (i = 0; i <= w2Contract.totalTransactions()-1; i++) {
    tranId = i;
    let tranHash = w2Contract.transactionIDs(i);
  let trDetails1 = w2Contract.transactions(tranHash);
  console.log(`Tran details ${trDetails1}`);
  console.log(`Tran Detail 1: ${trDetails1[1]}`);
  console.log(`Tran Detail 2: ${trDetails1[2]}`);
  console.log(`Tran Detail 0: ${trDetails1[0]}`);
  var tableRef =   document.getElementById('t02').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  // Insert a row at the end of the table
  let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);

  // Insert a cell in the row at index 0
  let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  // Append a text node to the cell
  let newText = document.createTextNode(`${tranId}`);
  newCell.appendChild(newText);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index 1
    let newCell1 = newRow.insertCell(1);
    // Append a text node to the cell
    let newText1 = document.createTextNode(`${trDetails1[1]}`);
    console.log(`newText1 at index 1 ${newText1}`);
        // w2 > w1
        if ((trDetails1[1] == '0xf9a2cb34b6b5fd7a2ac0c2e9b2b9406d6daffbd4') && 
        (trDetails1[2] == '0x180893a0ec847fa8c92786791348d7d65916acbb')) {
          newText1.textContent = 'Stock In'
        } else if  
          (trDetails1[1] == '0x180893a0ec847fa8c92786791348d7d65916acbb') {
          newText1.textContent = 'Pier Company'
        } else if (trDetails1[1] == '0xf9a2cb34b6b5fd7a2ac0c2e9b2b9406d6daffbd4') {
          newText1.textContent = 'Warehouse Company'
        }  
        newCell1.appendChild(newText1);

        // Insert a cell in the row at index 2
        let newCell2 = newRow.insertCell(2);
        // Append a text node to the cell
        let newText2 = document.createTextNode(`${trDetails1[2]}`);
        console.log(`newText1 at index 2 ${newText1}`);

        if (trDetails1[2] == '0xf9a2cb34b6b5fd7a2ac0c2e9b2b9406d6daffbd4') {
          newText2.textContent = 'Warehouse Company'
        }  
        if (trDetails1[2] == '0x180893a0ec847fa8c92786791348d7d65916acbb') {
          newText2.textContent = 'Pier Company'
        }
        if (trDetails1[2] == '0xc8f717ba9593dc9d45c4518cf444d2cbd08af24d') {
          newText2.textContent = 'Removal'
        }
          newCell2.appendChild(newText2);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index 3
    let newCell3 = newRow.insertCell(3);
    // Append a text node to the cell
    let newText3 = document.createTextNode(`${trDetails1[0]}`);
    console.log(`newText3 at index 3 ${newText3}`);
    newCell3.appendChild(newText3);

        // Insert a cell in the row at index 4
        let newCell4 = newRow.insertCell(4);
        // Append a text node to the cell
        let newText4 = document.createTextNode(`${trDetails1[3]}`);
        console.log(`newText1 at index 4 ${newText4}`);
        if (trDetails1[3] ) {
          newText4.textContent = 'Confirmed'
        } else {
          newText4.textContent = 'Pending'
        }  
        newCell4.appendChild(newText4);
     }

});
```